# async mkdir is throwing existing error but it is not in node.js

Tags: node.js, fs, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory in node.js and ignore the exception if the directory already exists.

Here is my code:

```js
const containerWorkDirectory = `/home/msh/Documents/arraba-api/app/build/plugin/images/images`;
const createDirectoryIfNotExists = async (
    dir,
    permission: boolean = true
) => {
    let output;

    try {
        output = await fsPromises.mkdir(dir, {
            mode: permission === true ? 0o775 : undefined,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        output = error.message;
        console.warn('Folder_Already_Exists');
    }

    return output;
};
const userDirectoryTreeCreation = async (userId) => {
    let userImagesDirectory = `${containerWorkDirectory}/${userId}`;
    let userProfileImagesDirectory = `${userImagesDirectory}/profile`;
    let userCarImagesDirectory = `${userImagesDirectory}/cars`;

    await createDirectoryIfNotExists(
        userImagesDirectory,
        true
    );
    await createDirectoryIfNotExists(
        userProfileImagesDirectory,
        true
    );
    await createDirectoryIfNotExists(
        userCarImagesDirectory,
        true
    );
};
userDirectoryTreeCreation(1);
```

But I got this error:

```json
{ [Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/home/msh/Documents/arraba-api/app/build/plugin/images/images/5/profile']
  errno: -17,
  code: 'EEXIST',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path:
   '/home/msh/Documents/arraba-api/app/build/plugin/images/images/5/profile' }
{ [Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/home/msh/Documents/arraba-api/app/build/plugin/images/images/5/cars']
  errno: -17,
  code: 'EEXIST',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path:
   '/home/msh/Documents/arraba-api/app/build/plugin/images/images/5/cars' }
```

But when I check the folder does not exist.
note that I am using Linux as os and folder do not exist but I got not an existing error from node.js file system.

Comment: what is the value of containerWorkDirectory?

Comment: I put it in code